# Weaver failure: unable to locate assemblies (no matching project) for: Temp/Assembly-CSharp.dll

Tags: unity-game-engine

I opened Unity for the first time in a while today and I'm unable to create new scripts of any type.  Both the normal and right click menus are missing the option:

[image]
[image]

Adding a script through the inspector creates a file, but yields these errors:

[image]

Although the file is created, it does not appear in either the project browser, or inspector panels.

Googling various parts of these errors actually gets a lot of posts, but almost all of them come down to "restart Unity", which isn't doing anything.

All of this is reproducible for me on a fresh project file.  I've tried restarting Unity and my computer, as well as reinstalling Unity from scratch.  I've also double checked that I have .NET installed properly (reinstalled, and `dotnet` command works in terminal).

Unity: 5.4.5p5

Mac OS 10.13.3

Comment: I know this isn't a lot to go on, I'm not sure what else to add.  If you know better than I do ask and I'll post away.

Comment: No sure how to help without mentioning Unity version

Comment: @Programmer derp - my bad.  Question updated

Comment: Looks like a bug and 5.4 is old. You need to update Unity. Unity 2017 is fine and that should fix your issue.

Comment: @Programmer oh wow - didn't see they changed their whole licensing/distribution system.  I was just using the built in "check for updates" option.  I'll try a fresh download from their site.

Comment: They changed that. There is also Unity 2018 beta now if you want to go that route. The current latest stable version now  is 2017.4.

Comment: @Programmer Worked perfectly, thanks!  If you want to make an answer out of that, it's deff worth the rep, otherwise I'll just self-answer.

Comment: I change the title to match the error so that others can find this in the future. I also linked the bug report in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/even-when-weaver-failure-unable-to-locate-assemblies-error-message-is-cleared-the-play-mode-cannot-be-entered) present in versions between *Unity 5.1* and *5.4*. It has been fixed in *Unity 5.5.0* and an update to *5.5.0* and above should fix it.

If updating to *Unity 5.5.0* which has the fix did not fix it then it's better to upgrade Unity to the latest version which is currently Unity *2017.4* at the time of posting this answer. This version should be able to get ride of that error.